# being interrupted while joining other threads

Tags: java, multithreading, join, exception, concurrency

How should I handle `InterruptedException` while joining other threads, assuming I don't actually anticipate being interrupted, and there is no sensible thing to do? Just swallow the exception?

```
try
{
    t.join();
    u.join();
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    // should not happen
}
```

Or should I put each `join` in its separate `try/catch`, so if an `InterruptedExeption` *does* happen while joining `t`, at least `u` gets a chance of being joined?

```
try
{
    t.join();
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    // should not happen
}
try
{
    u.join();
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    // should not happen
}
```

Or should I defensively swallow the exceptions in a loop, so I will eventually join both threads, even if some malicious guy tries to interrupt me?

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        t.join();
        break;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // no way, Jose!
    }
}
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        u.join();
        break;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // no way, Jose!
    }
}
```

On a side note, is there any case where `InterruptedExeption` doesn't make my code look ugly? :)

Comment: Why do you handle concurrency this way? Why should not you use fork/join? - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: @Manimaran - I agree it is better to use java.util.concurrent, but fork/join is not available until Java 7.

Comment: @Paul - Though it is not released yet, the concept is what I was talking about! We use a similar type of approach using the current(1.6) java.util.concurrent. We latch threads using Callable, Future and CountDownLatch. I'll edit my comment a bit to convey my point correctly!

Comment: Oops, time up! I couldn't edit :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something shouldn't happen, you probably want to know if it ever *does* happen - and the best way of making it obvious is often to throw a `RuntimeException` of some description (e.g. `IllegalStateException`). If you're not anticipating the possibility of being interrupted, that suggests the system is in a state you're not really happy to support, so I wouldn't then try to keep going - aborting quickly is often the best option here.

You may want to write a helper method which does this for you, to make the calling code cleaner.

Comment: Fail fast is a good principal, if you can afford a server randomly restarting when it encounters an uncaught unchecked exception.

Comment: @Rob: A server should usually catch anything thrown by each *request*. You don't want the server to go down just because there's a NullPointerException somewhere. Of course if *all* the requests start failing (or just a significant proportion), it's worth having monitoring which will start using a different server and restart the bad one... and possibly page someone.

Comment: uncaught NPE will just make the thread exit but virtually any server has some handler (to log at least). I am not a fan of hard process restart b/c there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: @bestsss: But that's my point - the process wouldn't restart. That request would be aborted, which is probably the right thing to do.